# Increment int pointer value - Doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment

I'm trying to print an int array, but it gives me an error.

> error: lvalue required as increment operand

```
int *a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d",*a);
    a++;
}
```

Comment: To declare an array you must use `int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` and not `int *a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`Also before entering your loop use int *p=a; then, in the loop, increment ++p. You cannont modify `a`, as it is an immutable pointer to the beginning of the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int *a[]` means an array of pointers to ints. You want an array of ints here, so use `int a[]`.

You can't increment `a` because `a` is an array, not a pointer. Arrays sometimes decay to pointers to the first element, but you can't modify that pointer. Instead, make a pointer pointing to the elements in the array like `int *p = a` or use the subscript operator like `a[i]` to access the elements.